# Can lattice attack work MSB or LSB are unkown but 16 bytes of private key are known?

Tags: signature, lattice-crypto, dsa, secp256k1

I have been reading about lattice attack on ECDSA when partial bits of nonce are known for amount of signatures, So i went through some source code trying to understand how it works.

First of all, Here are the formulas i know.

```
pk = d*G
r => (k*G).x mod n
s = (k^-1*(z+r*d)) mod n
k = s^-1*(z+r*d) mod n
d = r^-1*(s*k-z) mod n
x = (s^-1*z)*G+(s^-1*r)*pk mod n
```

So lattice attack seems to solve `k = s^-1*(z+r*d) mod n` and then `d = r^-1*(s*k-z)` mod n but in my case i do not have partial bits of `k` and enough signatures but i have 10 signatures and 16 bytes(128 most significant bits) of private key and i thought i could somehow modify the code to recover private key.

Here is my rough draft of the process:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix, symbols, Eq, solve, mod_inverse

# Define B
B = 2**(256-32)

# Initialize Mtilde and Rtilde as lists
Mtilde = [B, 0]
Rtilde = [0, B/p]

# Define your list of signatures SIGs
SIGs = [...]

# Calculate Mtilde and Rtilde based on SIGs
for sig in SIGs:
    m, r, s = sig
    m_tilde = (mod_inverse(s, p) * m) % p# change mod_inverse r,p*sk
    r_tilde = (mod_inverse(s, p) * r) % p#hange mod_inverse r,p*h
    Mtilde.append(m_tilde)
    Rtilde.append(r_tilde)

# Convert Mtilde and Rtilde into matrices
Mtilde = Matrix([Mtilde])
Rtilde = Matrix([Rtilde])

# Define p
p = ...

# Construct the diagonal submatrix Pdiag with p entries
Pdiag = -p * Matrix.eye(len(SIGs))

# Construct the lower left n x 2 zero block matrix Z
Z = Matrix.zeros(len(SIGs), 2)

# Construct the final matrix M assembling all blocks
M = Matrix.hstack(Z, Pdiag)
M = Matrix.vstack(Mtilde, Rtilde, M)

# Run the LLL algorithm
L, U = M.LLL()

# Check if any valid nonce was found
found = False
for row in L.tolist():
    if found:
        break
    for i in range(len(SIGs)):
        if found:
            break
        m, r, s = SIGs[i]
        # Skip the first two vector components we used to improve LLL
        solk = row[i + 2]
        # LLL might have swapped the sign of found short vectors
        for k in [solk, -solk]:
            d = (mod_inverse(r, p) * (k * s - m)) % p
            if d * G == P:
                print("Private key found!", d)
                found = True
                break
```

and my private key is like this:

```
70559122851704632926726513761106203720300000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

where zeros are the part that is unknown.

In theory an algorithm that finds `k` from signatures using partial bits would possibly recover `d`, So i ask the experts in cryptography and math.

Can lattice attack algorithm be modified to recover `LSB` of private key given enough signatures?